# Normed space between $H^{0+}$ and $L^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Cosider a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with consider the following condition.
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{|\widehat{f}(x)|}{1+|x|^{3/2}}dx<+\infty \, .\qquad\mbox{(*)} \, $$
Of course if $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for some $s>0$, condition (*) is satisfied. I`m asking if there is some Banach space $X\subset L^2$ such that

1) Every $f\in X$ satisfies condition (*)

2) $H^s\subset X$ for every $s>0$

3) I can interpolate between $X$ and $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Thank you for any suggestion